# Unable to have two versions of the same app on the one iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, bundle, target, versions

I have two versions of my app. I'm trying to keep a copy of each on my iPhone for testing purposes.

In my build settings, my bundle display name is *${PRODUCT_NAME}* and I've given each version of my app a different product name (eg "v92" and "v10"). When I install each version to my iPhone, they both appear side by side with different names, however one will work normally, and the other will immediately close the moment it's opened. If I delete the version that works normally, the other will start working.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this one too and eventually solved it.  I know the solution had to do with changing something in the information property list, but I'm not sure exactly what.  I would suggest making sure that all of the following are different for your two versions:

bundle display name
executable file
bundle identifier
bundle name

Comment: thanks :) the key seems to be to ensure a different bundle identifier

Answer (score 4):

I think the apps are distinguished on the device by the App Id and not the product name. I dont know how you were able to install two apps only by changing the product name. When i mistakenly installed a different app with same app id but different product name the original app was overwritten.

Try creating a separate app id for the new version only for testing. That might solve your problem but make sure you use the correct app id when you submit your app.

EDIT: It might not be the right solution if you are doing some app id specific stuff (like APNS) in you app.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can create two app id's and two provisioning profiles in your developers account. Then you'll be able to install your 2 versions like a two different apps. It's an ugly solution, but it definitely works.